# snapshot.data returns null in streambuilder but shows correct value just before I return data model with snapshot data

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream-builder

This is the code for my stream builder.

```
    StreamBuilder<RatesData>(
          stream: DatabaseRatesService(fid: fid).ratesData,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) // Doesn't get off from this condition and keeps loading.
              return LoadingLogin(); // A simple loading widget
            RatesData ratesData = snapshot.data;
              print(ratesData.fid);
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    child: Text(
                      ratesData.fid,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
)
```

And this is the class where I have all the database queries. I seem to have successfully gotten data from firebase but it isn't showing in my stream builder. I'm suspecting that the data isn't getting injected into the data model I created but have no idea how.

```
class DatabaseRatesService{

  final String fid;
  DatabaseRatesService({this.fid});

DocumentReference get(){
  return Firestore.instance.collection('rates').document(fid);}

  RatesData _ratesDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    print(snapshot.data); // I put this here for testing purposes / it returns correct data here
    return RatesData(
      firstHourWeekday: snapshot.data['FirstHourWeekday'],
      firstHourWeekend: snapshot.data['FirstHourWeekend'],
      fid: fid,
      ratesWeekday: snapshot.data['RatesWeekday'],
      ratesWeekend: snapshot.data['RatesWeekend'],
      );
  }
  Stream<RatesData> get ratesData {
    DocumentReference ratesDocument = get();
    return ratesDocument.snapshots()
    .map(
      _ratesDataFromSnapshot
      );
  }

}
```

UPDATE: It wasn't returning null. I tried getting the error message. The message says " 'type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List' ".

Comment: Do you know what is the exact error ?  You can quickly check it with if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error.toString);

Comment: Never thought of that. I just assumed it was returning null. The error says "type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' "
I have Strings and String arrays in my data model. Can Streambuilders not handle arrays?

Comment: You need cast dynamic to required type here.  Inside your _ratesDataFromSnapshot to cast dynamic list to string list try using snapshot.data['field-name'].cast<String>().toList()

Comment: That fixed it, and is working just as I wanted to. Thanks. Could you please post the answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59853842/snapshot-data-returns-null-in-streambuilder-but-shows-correct-value-just-before?noredirect=1#comment105840672_59853842), you will need to edit your method **_ratesDataFromSnapshot** to handle non-primitive data types and also null values (if the returned data does not have the field you are trying to read)

```
snapshot.data['field'].cast<String>().toList() ?? List() // handle the null case as well with empty list
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a formatting issue, you are missing the {} braces around if statement
try below

if (!snapshot.hasData) // Doesn't get off from this condition and keeps loading.
              {return LoadingLogin();}